# returning the column values as a list or else 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had a query where i am trying to get the results of a query, the query can have multiple rows or it can be empty, i am trying if it is empty, it should return me 0 for a column i am looking which is called as `sequence`

My query is like this:

```
select CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sequence
            from dbo.mytable
```

it returns me the either `1` or `0`, for 1 i want that column should return me values or it should combine all the rows and return me the value of that column as list like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: it should show me values but instead it is showing me 0 in all columns, the screenshot is for the values i should get http://prntscr.com/js311w

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.  Right now it is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MY_COUNT > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SEQUENCE
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS MY_COUNT
FROM
DBO.MYTABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row in the result set, simply do:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as sequence
```

from mytable;

If you care at all about performance, the more efficient method is:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from dbo.mytable) then 1 else 0
        end) as sequence
```